# Where can I find "gen_checkpoint_ops" of inception v4?

Tags: python, tensorflow

***When I was debuging inception v4, there has a message:***

"

```
22     from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops import gen_checkpoint_ops

23     from tensorflow.contrib.util import loader

24     from tensorflow.python.framework import dtypes

   ImportError: cannot import name gen_checkpoint_ops
```

".
***But I can't find a module or package named "gen_checkpoint_ops".***
***I don't know how to resolve this problem.***
*The code was downloaded form: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/README.md#pre-trained-models*

Help!

Comment: I found the problem already! I have used the unappropriated version slim modules. Just copied and replaced some *.py files.